# Looping over list combined with nested list in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have two lists that I want to loop over together. One contains a list of hosts, and the second contains a list of lists, where the nested list is a set of items used to repeat a task on each of the hosts. Here's a simple example:

list of hosts

```
hosts:
  - host1
  - host2
```

list of operations to perform on each host. the `hosts` and `ops` list are the same length, such that `op1` and `op2` should be executed on `host1`, and `op{3,4,5}` should be executed on `host2`.

```
ops:
  -
    - op1
    - op2
  -
    - op3
    - op4
    - op5
```

Then I'd like to use these two lists to repeat a task

```
- name: my task
  module: "{{ item.1 }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item.0 }}"
  with_together:
    - hosts
    - ops
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work since `item.1` will be a list (I'd like to repeat `my_task` for each op). And something like `with_nested` doesn't work either since I don't want to repeat *all* the operations present in `ops` on each host.

I'm hoping for a succinct solution so I can avoid building some intermediate data structures.

Comment: since the ops are tied with the hosts (ops1,2 for host1 and ops3,4,5 for host2), why not making a single data structure in first place ? a list of hosts, each host has a list of ops.

Comment: @chenchuk that is definitely one option, and certainly what i'm going to do if i don't find a better way. however, after looking through documentation, it seems that there a huge variety of looping options and any of those can be combined with various jinja things like zip, map, etc... so really this question is also about discovering looping techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to reformat your files like this:

```
ops:
  - list:
      - ops1
      - ops1
  - list:
      - ops3
      - ops4
      - ops5
```

And,

```
- name: my task
  module: "{{ item[1] }}.*:ALL"
  delegate_to: "{{ item[0] }}"
  with_together:
    - "{{ hosts }}"
    - "{{ ops.list }}"
```

Using my phone, so check the indentations.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put those lists into `host_vars/host1` and `host_vars/host2`.

So, `host_vars/host1`:

```
ops:
   - op1
   - op2
```

And `host_vars/host2`:

```
ops:
   - op3
   - op4
   - op5
```

Then your play can just be:

```
- name: my task
  module: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ ops }}"
```